# Facebook's Embedded Posts not visible

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to show posts I have posted via my facebook app.

Using embedded post, it only shows posts which I have posted on my own (user), not via my app.

I switched all the privacy settings to public, at least I did not find any more options which could prevent the post to be public.

If I am logging-out, I also can not see posts on the chronic which where posted by my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your app “live” on top of Status&Review tab.

Comment: thx, is there a need that facebook reviews it. for posting as user?

Comment: Setting the app live does not require review. If you want to ask users other than those that have a role in the app for any permissions (besides the three basic ones), then you need to get those permissions reviewed before you can ask normal users for them.